# NPM Dependency Tree Solution

Tags: npm, github-actions

I have a package, let's call it `pkg A`, that has `pkg B` as a dependency. `pkg B` has a list of dependencies that are scoped with `*` like so:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "pkgC": "*",
    "pkgD": "*",
    "pkgE": "*",
  }
```

Currently, `pkg B` is installed `@latest` in CI environment in `pkgA` Github workflow. When installed, `pkgB` gets updated at latest, but `pkgB` dependencies within `pkgA` `package-lock.json` are not updated to latest registry version per wildcards in `pkgB` `package.json`.

Am I missing something about the dependency tree resolution for `pkgB` wildcard dependencies? Not sure if there is a specific npm CLI instruction I can provide to ensure that when `pkgB` is updated in `pkgA`, all of `pkgB` dependencies are updated to latest as well.

I looked at npm CLI docs to see if there was anything I was missing regarding tree resolution for dependencies.